# R Markdown: the code chunks run, but getting errors when knitting

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using RStudio Cloud.  I'm running an RMarkdown doc, when I run the code chunks in the doc they work fine, but when I'm trying to knit I get errors. Before I used the code "knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)" the doc wouldn't knit at all (error message was saying objects couldn't be found); now it knits BUT I get the error message "## Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title): unable to start data viewer" when I try to View(dataframes) that I've created (the data frames I created show up in the global environment but not in my file path directory, which is /cloud/project).  I'm guessing that RMarkdown can't find these since they are in a different file path? I'm also assuming that files in the global directory aren't available for RMarkdown to knit, so how do I get them to be available for RMarkdown to knit? Thank you!

Comment: So you are trying a knit a document that contains the code `View(dataframes)`. Would you try to comment out that `View(dataframes)` line and knit again?

Comment: @shafee I've omitted the View lines from the code, and it knits without the error message, but I'd like to try and show the viewed dataframes in the markdown document.

Comment: then simply add the data frame object name in the chunk

Comment: @shafee  sorry to keep asking questions, I'm a newbie!  How exactly do I do that?  TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing View you can just do this.

````
```{r}
df # assuming df is your data.frame object name
```
````

this will print your whole dataframe `df` in the knitted document.

Comment: thanks!  That worked!  I would not have expected such a simple solution :)

Comment: If that work for you can you kindly accept my answer?? see here [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)